# wildfly: how to set minimum or core threads for a worker in io subsystem

Tags: servlets, threadpool, wildfly, nonblocking, undertow

I define a worker in io subsystem of wildfly 9.0.1 as follow:

```
<worker name="fileUpload_io_worker" io-threads="100" task-max-threads="100"/>
```

and use it in underow subsystem for setting async non blocking io threads in servlet.
When i send for example 40 concurrent http request to server, only 20 thread in server, process requests concurrently and only when i send 200 concurrent request, all 100 thread (max thread) activate and process requests. in fact server queue half of arrived requests.
How can i set minimum or core thread count to 100 and force server to process all 100 requests concurrently?

Is there a config like core-thread-count for setting minimum threads?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no such configuration option.

Comment: thank for your answer. how wildfly determine thread count and why in my tests, half of requests are processed concurrently?

Comment: If you have additional questions you should create a new Question rather than trying to build the conversation as a set of comments on an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There was a parameter `task-core-threads` in [Wildfly 8.2](http://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/8.2.0.Final/subsystem/io/worker/index.html)

but since it was not implemented, it was removed in [Wildfly 9](http://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/9.0.0.CR2/subsystem/io/worker/index.html)

see this thread:
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/261489